# calculate total time

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some json data which contain different time on each day. I have to calculate sum of time according to day.Here is my JSON

```
   [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "monday_NT":"3:45",
        "monday_TH":"2:45",
        "monday_DT":"4:45",
        "monday_DTH":"2:45",
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "monday_NT":"2:45",
        "monday_TH":"5:45",
        "monday_DT":"3:45",
        "monday_DTH":"1:49",
    }
]
```

I have done this calculation but I used too many variables for this calculation.Here is my code for monday:

```
var monday_NT_hr=0;
var monday_TH_hr=0;
var monday_DT_hr=0;
var monday_DTH_hr=0;
var monday_NT_min=0;
var monday_TH_min=0;
var monday_DT_min=0;
var monday_DTH_min=0;
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    for(var index in data[i])
    {
        if(index=="monday_NT")
        {
            monday_NT_hr +=data[i][index].split(":")[0]; 
            monday_NT_min +=data[i][index].split(":")[1];
        }
        if(index=="monday_TH")
        {
            monday_TH_hr +=data[i][index].split(":")[0];
            monday_TH_min +=data[i][index].split(":")[1];
        }
        if(index=="monday_DT")
        {
            monday_DT_hr +=data[i][index].split(":")[0];
            monday_DT_min +=data[i][index].split(":")[1];
        }
        if(index=="monday_DTH")
        {
            monday_DTH_hr +=data[i][index].split(":")[0];
            monday_DTH_min +=data[i][index].split(":")[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway so less variable is used for this calculation?
Please help.

Comment: You need to be much more clear here. What are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by 'sum of time'?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using that many variables, it's well written and easy to understand. An alternative would be to use '?' and ':' operators

Comment: I think it looks fine, no change necessary to me

Comment: You could write a function that converts the times into `seconds` then adds that to a total. So that you can reuse this function for each of: `monday_NT`, `monday_TH`, etc. More maintainable code because you then you aren't duplicating that logic 4 times for each.

Comment: @tmwoods Here sum of time means i have to calculate hours and min.
for example monday_NT="3:45",is a time value and calculate sum of each monday_NT. Similarly for all monday_TH, monday_DT and monday_DTH

Answer (score 1):

If I can assume that each of the values listed is a time in hours and minutes and you want to find the sum of all of the times, you could potentially consolidate your code.

```
var total_time = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var attr in data[i]) {
    if (attr != 'id') {
      total_time += getSeconds(data[i][attr]);
    }
  }
}

total_time = secToFormatted(total_time); // Total time in a formatted string

function getSeconds(strTime) {
  // Convert a string time to seconds
}

function secToFormatted(seconds) {
  // Convert seconds into hours and minutes string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set up two objects named `hours` and `minutes` and add the sums based on the exact key names in the original data:

```
var hours = {},
    minutes = {};

for (var i = 0, il = data.length; i < il; i++) {
    for (var k in data[i]) {
        var timeSplit = data[i][k].split(':'),
            hour = parseInt(timeSplit[0], 10),
            min = parseInt(timeSplit[1], 10);

        hours[k] = hours[k] ? hours[k] + hour : hour;
        minutes[k] = minutes[k] ? minutes[k] + min : min;
    }
}

console.log(hours);
// {id: 3, monday_NT: 5, monday_TH: 7, monday_DT: 7, monday_DTH: 3}
console.log(minutes);
// {id: NaN, monday_NT: 90, monday_TH: 90, monday_DT: 90, monday_DTH: 94}
```

You can ignore the `id`.

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTQjp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This should be lot better: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaMxb/))

```
var monday_NT= {min:0, hr:0};
var monday_TH={min:0, hr:0};
var monday_DT={min:0, hr:0};
var monday_DTH={min:0, hr:0};

function splitSum(obj, data) {  
    data = data.split(":");
    obj.hr += Number(data[0]);
    obj.min += Number(data[1]); 
}

for(var i in arr) {    
    splitSum(monday_NT, arr[i].monday_NT);
    splitSum(monday_TH, arr[i].monday_TH);
    splitSum(monday_DT, arr[i].monday_DT);
    splitSum(monday_DTH, arr[i].monday_DTH);
}
```

As per your example

```
monday_NT.min
```

would be equivalent to

```
monday_NT_min
```

---

Though I believe all this hard work gives no additional benefit.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate time difference of two times in 24hr formate

```
var time1 = "22:00"
var time2 = "01:00"
```

Ans: 3:00 Hrs

```
var c = a.split(":")
var d = b.split(":")
var aH = parseInt(c[0])
var aM = parseInt(c[1])
var bH = parseInt(d[0])
var bM = parseInt(d[1])


if(aM > bH) {
 bH -= 1
 bM += 60
}
if(aH > bH) {
    bH += 24
}
var hour = bH - aH
var min = bM - aM
console.log( hour + ":" + min)
```

[**See Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dum43ky7/)

Comment: Please add the code to here, because it's currently a link only answer